# Reading data from xlsx into Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

**Scenario:** I put together this little Frankenstein of a code (with some awesome help from SO users) to get data from excel files and put into a pandas dataframe.

**What I am trying to do:** I am trying to get data from files that may contain one or more worksheets of data. After that I intend to organize the dataframe accordingly. For example:

```
date1    identifier 1    bid     ask
date1    identifier 2    bid     ask
date1    identifier 3    bid     ask
date2    identifier 1    bid     ask
date2    identifier 3    bid     ask
date3    identifier 4    bid     ask
date3    identifier 5    bid     ask
```

**Obs1:** Each file can have values for "Bid", "Ask" or both, each in a separate worksheet.

**Obs2:** The identifiers and dates may or may not be the same across files.

**What I did so far:** My current code reads the files, and each worksheet. If it follows the condition, it attaches to a specific dataframe. Then it fixes the column headings.

**Issue:** When my code runs, it yields two empty dataframes for some reason.

**Question:** How can I account for different worksheets and output the values accordingly (to the structure above) to a dataframe?

**Current Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import glob, os
import datetime as dt
from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib as mpl
from openpyxl import load_workbook


directory = os.path.join("C:\\","Users\\DGMS\\Desktop\\final 2")        
list_of_dfs = []
dfbid = pd.DataFrame()
dfask = pd.DataFrame()

for root,dirs,files in os.walk(directory):

    for file in files:

        f = os.path.join(root, file)

        wb = load_workbook(f)

        for sheet in wb.worksheets:
            if sheet == "Bid":
                dfbid = pd.concat([dfbid, pd.read_excel(f, "Bid")])
                for i in range(1,len(dfbid.columns)):
                    dfbid.columns.values[i] = pd.to_datetime(dfbid.columns.values[i])

            elif sheet == "Ask":
                dfask = pd.concat([dfask, pd.read_excel(f, "Ask")])
                for i in range(1,len(dfask.columns)):
                    dfask.columns.values[i] = pd.to_datetime(dfask.columns.values[i])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Separate the different things your code does in different functions.

- look for the excel-files
- read the excel-files
- convert the content to `datetime`
- concatenate the DataFrames

This way you can check and inspect each step separately instead of have it all intertwined

## Look for the excel-files

```
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path

root_dir = Path(r"C:\Users\DGMS\Desktop\final 2")

files = root_dir.glob('**/*.xlsx')
```

## Read the excel-files

Read each file and return the worksheets `'Bid'` and `'Ask'`, then generate 2 lists of Dataframes

```
def parse_workbook(file):
    d = pd.read_excel(file, sheetname=None)
    return d.get('Bid', None), d.get('Ask', None)

df_bid_dfs, df_ask_dfs = zip(*(parse_workbook(file) for file in files))
```

## Convert the content to `datetime`

```
def parse_datetime(df):
    for column_name, column in df.iteritems():
        df[column_name] = pd.to_datetime(column)
    return df
```

## Concatenate the DataFrames

```
df_bid = pd.concat(parse_datetime(df) for df in df_bid_dfs if df)
df_ask = pd.concat(parse_datetime(df) for df in df_ask_dfs if df)
```

## testing `parse_datetime` and the concatenation

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(['20170718'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(['20170719'])
df_bid_dfs = (df1, df2)
```

> ```
> pd.concat(parse_datetime(df) for df in df_bid_dfs)
> ```

```
    0
0   2017-07-18
0   2017-07-19
```

Comment: As far as I know `concat` works with a generator expression. Perhaps not in all versions?

Comment: Many Thanks for the answer. One question regarding the concatenate procedure: Supposing some of my files have some repeated columns (dates) or repeated rows (identifiers), my objective with concatenate is to add any new column to the end (left of all columns), and any new row to the end (bottom). If there is already a column, it just adds a new row and if there is already that row, it just adds to the new column. Can the concatenate procedure do that automatically? Or do I need to concatenate one axis at a time?

Comment: Btw, I tried running your code, and I have two problems: First I keep getting that "file" is not defined. Second, I believe the code does not account for files that have either just "Bid" or only "Ask" worksheets. Is it ok to account for that in a loop?

Comment: what line gives the error that `file` is not defined? You do know the `Path.glob` returns an iterator which exhausts when iterated over? I added the code to account for when `bid` or `Ask` are not in the workbook

Comment: I changed that part of the code, and now it yield a "unknown string format error". Preceded by: 
  File "C:\Users\DGMS\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dateutil\parser.py", line 1168, in parse
    return DEFAULTPARSER.parse(timestr, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\DGMS\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dateutil\parser.py", line 559, in parse
    raise ValueError("Unknown string format")

Comment: What did you do to try to debug it? I would start to find out which file is posing this problem and then examine the content of that file. The easiest would be to do that in an IDE with a debugger that pauses an Exception

Comment: From What I got by debugging, on the parsing for the columns, it does it for the first dataframe and stops after that. I am currently checking the formatting of the second file, but it seems to be normal. Also, it appear to be forming just the first list of dfs (for Bid). For (ask) it does not do it for some reason.